# object has no attribute error in gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am getting the error as 'r1' object has no attribute 'Frame_Display'.

```
class gui:

def __init__(self,master):
    Frame_Menu = LabelFrame(root, bd=1,text='Menu', labelanchor=N, height=550, width=200, relief=SUNKEN)
    Frame_Menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Frame_Display = LabelFrame(root, bd=1, text='System Layout', labelanchor=N, height=550, width=750, relief=SUNKEN)
    Frame_Display.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)

class r1(gui):

def __init__(self, level=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(gui, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    vf1r1_button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="VF1R1",bg="red",state=DISABLED).grid(row=8,column=2,pady=(1,0))
    vf2r1_button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="VF2R1",bg="red",state=DISABLED).grid(row=10,column=2)
    r1_Button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="Reactor 1",bg="red").grid(row=9,column=4,padx=(30,0))

root=tk.Toplevel()
root.title("GUI Using classes")
a = r1()
root.mainloop()
```

****edit 1 - traceback error added below****

```
runfile('C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/GUI-Classes.py', wdir='C:/Users/rohit/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-4b3be26cf4d4>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/GUI-Classes.py', wdir='C:/Users/rohit/Desktop')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/GUI-Classes.py", line 62, in <module>
a = r1()

  File "C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/GUI-Classes.py", line 50, in __init__
vf1r1_button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="VF1R1",bg="red",state=DISABLED).grid(row=8,column=2,pady=(1,0))

AttributeError: 'r1' object has no attribute 'Frame_Display'
```

I want to place the buttons in r1 on the main gui and in frame_display

Comment: show the complete traceback error please

Comment: @InAFlash i have added please check

Comment: Inside class `gui`, you should replace `Frame_Display` with `self.Frame_Display` in order to define it as an attribute.

Comment: @LaurentH. tried that too, same error

Comment: @Rohit HR, same error occures, because your `super` call is invalid. The right one is `super(r1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. Combine this with @Laurent H. comment and with `a = r1(master=root)` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems with your original code that explains the error:

1. `Frame_Display` is not defined as an attribute inside class `gui`: you have to use `self.Frame_Display` instead of `Frame_Display`
2. You wrongly call the `__init__()` function of the superclass gui from the class `r1`: to do so, you have to write `gui.__init__(self, ...)`

Finally here is a (simplified) code that works on my side, fixing also other little issues:

```
import tkinter as tk

class gui:

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame_Menu = tk.LabelFrame(root, bd=1,text='Menu', height=550, width=200)
        Frame_Menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.Frame_Display = tk.LabelFrame(root, bd=1, text='System Layout', height=550, width=750)
        self.Frame_Display.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=1)

class r1(gui):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        gui.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        vf1r1_button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="VF1R1",bg="red").grid(row=8,column=2,pady=(1,0))
        vf2r1_button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="VF2R1",bg="red").grid(row=10,column=2)
        r1_Button=tk.Button(self.Frame_Display,text="Reactor 1",bg="red").grid(row=9,column=4,padx=(30,0))


root=tk.Toplevel()
root.title("GUI Using classes")
a = r1(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good answer. Only flaw is you define `def __init__(self, master):` but then use `root` in initiating the widgets, which in this case is actually the global `root`.